# Is $u$ substitution nothing more than a change of coordinate but in $1$ dimension

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution, change-of-variable

Often while solving integrals, it becomes easier to solve it, by transforming into polar, spherical and other coordinate systems, from our standard cartesian coordinates.

My question is, is a simple $u$-substitution essentially the same thing, just in one dimension ? Is it nothing more than a simple change of coordinates, where we move from $x$ coordinate to $u$ coordinates ?

Moreover, is coordinate transformation or $u$ substitution, just a trivial change of basis, while integral transforms represent a standard change of basis. Can someone explain why one is considered trivial while the other is 'standard' ?

Comment: I don't know that one-dimensional substitutions are all that trivial.  [Weierstass's substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution), $t=\tan(\theta/2)$ transforms rational functions in trigonometric functions of $\theta$ into ordinary rational functions in $t$.  Is that trivial?

Comment: @lulu when I said trivial I didn't mean easy. I meant that some people described it as a trivial change of basis, while integral transforms as standard change of basis. However in both cases, we are expressing a function in a different variable. So, why is one considered a trivial change of variable, while the other as standard change in variable.

Comment: @lulu in a sense, the difference between u substitution and integral transform, because to me, they are both doing the same thing, changing a function from $f(x)$ to some $g(u)$ or $h(k)$ or something

Comment: I don't understand.  Referring to something as a "trivial change in variable"  or a "standard change of variable" are hardly precise definitions.  Personally, I would never use "standard" unless I was referring to something universally recognized, though again I don't think this is a precisely defined notion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [integration by substitution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) is a special case of the following theorem:
$\newcommand{\d}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$
Let $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $\Phi\colon U\to V$ a $C^1$-diffeomorphism. Then a measurable function $F\colon V\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable iff $$G:=|\det\circ\d\Phi|\cdot(F\circ\Phi)$$ is integrable$^1$ and$$\int_V F=\int_U G$$
(Both integrals are defined with respect to the Lebesgue measure.) More generally, we can consider the [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral) and then this theorem also holds if $f$ is a function to a [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space).

---

$^1$ Since $\phi\in C^1(U,V)$, $\d\Phi\in C(U,\mathbb R^{n\times n})$ and hence $|\det\circ\d\Phi|\in C(U,\mathbb R)$ is the composition of continuous functions.

Comment: And the formulas for integration using polar coordinates, spherical coordinates, etc, are special cases of this theorem.

Comment: @littleO Exactly :) And the case $n=1$ of this theorem is actually stronger than the usual integration by substitution (which is an immediate corollary of the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)): While the latter only applies to continuous functions on compact intervals, this allows us to compute the integral of functions with a singularity (e.g. at the origin), which appear all the time in the study of PDEs.

Comment: @Filippo ah so, u substituition and change of coordinates are essentially the same thing, they are special cases of this theorem. However, what then, is an integral transform ? Even that looks like a change of variable, like from $x$ to $p$, as in the fourier transform

Comment: @Filippo are those, related to this theorem too ?

Comment: @Filippo being from a physics background, I have to admit, this terminology is a little foreign to me. 'Here we integrate over the respective domains with respect to the Lebesgue measure.' - this basically translates to ' we can integrate in the respective domain, with the appropriate jacobian' does it ?

Comment: @RayPalmer A change of units would be a linear and invertible function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (and the restriction to an open interval is a diffeomorphism between open intervals), so you can apply my theorem. Does this answer your first question?

Comment: @Filippo yes it does, thanks :)

Comment: @RayPalmer Great :) Okay, then let me come to your second question. Have you learned the definition of the integral in your classes? Or have you simply been told that integrals exist and what properties they have?

Comment: @Filippo can you elaborate, what do you mean the definition of integrals ? DO you mean integral transform ?

Comment: @Filippo in that case, I've been told only that it lets me go from position space to momentum space, or time space to frequency space. But in variable substitution, aren't we doing the same thing ? Going from x space to u space ?

Comment: @RayPalmer I know that it is common to call the Fourier transform a change of variables, but this has nothing to do with the theorem in my answer. The Fourier transform of a function $f$ is another function $\hat{f}$, i.e. you can think of the fourier transform as a linear operator between two function spaces. In my answer, I only consider the integral of a function and by a coordinate change I mean a bijection between two open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Filippo can you please elaborate on what the fourier transform actually does, and how is it different from the answer that you've written ?

Comment: The Fourier transform maps integrable functions to continuous functions, i.e. it is a function $L^1(\mathbb R^n)\to C(\mathbb R^n)$. In the context of my answer, a coordinate change is just a bijection between two subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. You need to be careful when saying that the Fourier transform is a change of variables, since there is not a function $\Phi\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ s.t. $\widehat{u}=u\circ\Phi$ for all $u\in L^1$.

Comment: @RayPalmer Sorry, I forgot to tag you.